# Take picture from camera and pass URI to another activity

Tags: java, android

When I try to get the URI on the onActivityResult() method, I get a null pointer exception.
I need to take a picture from the device camera and then pass the URI to the next activity.
That's my actual code:

```
public void takePicFromCamera(View view){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        try {
            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "IMG_FOLDER");


    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "profile_img.jpg"));
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode != 0) {
        Uri sel_img = data.getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("uri", sel_img.toString());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode != 0){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("uri", imageUri.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

The RateActivity after I take the image, doesn't start

Comment: There is not supposed to be a `Uri` returned via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Your `data` `Intent` should have [a thumbnail `Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPhotoView) that you can try to access. Or, you can [use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to *provide* a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath), which the camera app is supposed to write the output to.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, I'm trying with extras.get("data"). But then, how should I retrieve the URI from this Bitmap?

Comment: @CommonsWare I edit my question if You want to check it

Comment: The simplest thing is to just pass that `Bitmap` to the next activity. It it already small enough to fit in an `Intent` extra -- that is how you got the `Bitmap` in the first place. So, instead of `putExtra("uri", imageUri.toString());`, use `putExtra("bitmap", bitmap);`.